# Basic approach for dynamically loading custom libraries in C for embedded devices

Tags: c

Currently, I'm working on an embedded system with the functionality to load specific subsets of the codebase depending on the boot configuration. However, I'm having trouble coming up with ideas on how to implement it properly.

**To provide more context:**

```
The project involves a fieldbus interface with the dynamic parts 
being the 'Frame Validation'  and 'Frame Interpretation'
```

**The architecture is as follows:**

```
The physical/IO layer and the application layer always remain the same
The physical/IO layer handles the SPI/UART/I2C hardware
The application layer manages R/W operations to the device memory map
```

In between these two layers, the raw frame received via the physical/IO layer needs to be validated:

```
Check CRC, and special markers
specific constraints, and so on ... you get the idea
```

and interpreted:

```
The first payload byte represents the number of payload bytes
The next two bytes indicate the R/W address
```

**My requirements are**

The codebase must be usable for different 'protocol specifications' building on the same physical/IO and application layer.

```
For example, one protocol uses CRC32, while another one uses CRC16, 
and a third one has no CRC at all but uses a 
special FRAME-START/-END marker that the others don't.
```

**My problem is:**

Of course, I could use build flags or if/else clauses in the code to make this possible, but this seems too cumbersome to me.

(1) If using build flags, I have to ship/maintain/orchestrate/manage different binaries. Also, the codebase becomes complex and (subjectively) hard to read.

(2) If using if/else statements, the codebase becomes slower and also (subjectively) harder to read.

**My idea is:**

To structure the codebase in a way that, when the controller is initialized, specific 'binaries' are used depending on the configuration. These 'binaries' are compiled seperatly and are always present in the controller flash (e.g. CRC16, CRC32_a, CRC32_b...). So, basically like a DLL.

These binaries can, but are not required to be, execuded from RAM. However, i'd like to keep them in flash and run them from flash.

**My question is:**

How would i do this?

I'm thinking about problems like:

- How to know where the libraries are located in the flash and how to assign the specific library to be used?
- How to compile the library files in such a way, that the code gets position independent and re-entrant?
- How to come up with a "file format" for the binaries? What information is required in the "file header" etc?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You will get better help if you focus your question on a particular aspect of the problem. And then, you need to explain what you tried to do, and explain how it failed.

Comment: Most embedded systems don't "load" any code. All the code that exists is in the flash. You can probably do something like what you (seem to) want using structures containing function pointers, but it's not entirely clear what you want.